# xsl "value-of" math with "format-number" variables

Tags: xslt, math

I'm new to xsl and have a problem. I always get "NaN" when i try to do the following:

```
<xsl:variable name="amount" select="format-number(ARTICLE_PRICE/PRICE_LINE_AMOUNT, '0,00')" />
<xsl:variable name="quantity" select="format-number($quantity, '0,0#')"/>
<xsl:value-of select="format-number($amount * $quantity, '0,00')" />
```

Can someone tell me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Could you show us the input values?

Answer (score 1):

One possible reason out of several:

The result of format-number() is a string; if the string cannot be converted back to a number - for example, if it contains a comma - then you cannot multiply by it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if i do it like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="quantity" select="format-number($quantity, '0,0#')"/>
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(ARTICLE_PRICE/PRICE_LINE_AMOUNT * $quantity, '0,00')" />
```

It works. Still curious why it didn't work if i set the variable "amount"..

Comment: "*It works.*" No it doesn't. You have a circular definition. And your format string is malformed.

Answer (score 0):

The 'NaN' value means you try to use format-number() on a value that is empty or not a valid number.
You have to test the value before using them as number, and formatting them before multiplying them is useless (if you don't use them elsewhere)